# js append div to only current parents child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` block that is repeated on the page for each product. I am using JS to cycle through all the instances of a `div` class and would like to move that `div` to another `div` in the same block. I wrote this:

```
$(value).appendTo('.product-image')
```

and it adds each `div` to all the `product-image` divs on the page. How can I add each `div` only to the `product-image` `div` that is a child of `$(values)` parent?

This did not work for me:

```
$(value).appendTo($(value).parent().find('.product-image'))
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i came up with this sulotion thanks !

```
ind++
var tryy = "try"+ind;
$(value).parent().find('.product-image').addClass(tryy);
var tryyy = '.'+tryy;
$(value).appendTo(tryyy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to select the first parent div.
 `$(value).appendTo($(value).parent('div:first()').find('.product-image'))`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you some ideas for implementation:

For example if you `value` element has `value` class:

```
$('.value:has(.product-image)').find('.product-image').each(function(){
     $(this).append(your_new_div)
});
```